# HTMLをWebBrowserコントロールに表示する方法

Tags: c#, winforms

```
String html = "<font color=\"#ff0000\">TestingHTML</font>";
webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

This code can do display HTML in `WebBrowser`.
But problem is sounds of Web Browser loading.
And Mouse Cursor become Waiting Cursor.

上記のコードでHTMLを`WebBrowser`に表示することはできます。
しかし、問題は`WebBrowser`の読み込み音がすることです。
そしてマウスカーソルは待ち状態になってしまいます。
`webBrowser1.DocumentText`を使う以外の方法でどうにか２つの問題を解決しつつ同じようにHTMLをプレビュー表示する方法をご存知ではありませんか？

Comment: お二方ともありがとうございます。無事に解決いたしました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebBrowser.Document.Write`を使用して`about:blank`に書き込めばナビゲーションとは認識されないので「ナビゲーションの完了」サウンドは鳴りません。

```
if (webBrowser1.Document == null)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
}
else
{
    webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(false);
}
webBrowser1.Document.Write(html);
```

カーソルは何か別の個所が原因ではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowserコントロールのナビゲーションサウンドは[Navigation Sound Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330734(v=vs.85).aspx#navigation_sound)のレジストリキーで制御します。

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
  SOFTWARE
    Microsoft
      Internet Explorer
        Main
          FeatureControl
            FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS
              contoso.exe = (DWORD) 00000001
```

ここで`contoso.exe`は実際の実行ファイル名を指定してください。なおデバッグの際、ホストプロセスを有効にした場合は`contoso.vhost.exe`になります。